# How to login with multiple users at a time using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have attached the screenshots of Http Request and CSV Data config. Please check and let me know where i am making mistake

I got the below response when i run this script

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in fragment at index 89: http://letsbac.colanonline.net/#/login?inputUsername=msinghzx4&inputPassword=A12345b&Sign In=submit
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:399)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[image]

Comment: Is your parameter name is really `Sign In` with space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to tick `Encode` box  where `Sign In` parameter is or change your `Sign In` to `Sign%20In` as special character in URLs need to be [Encoded](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)
2. I doubt that you use correct method, my expectation is that you should use `POST` in Method dropdown

   [image: JMeter POST URL Encode]
3. The easiest way to build a proper request is recording it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as your test plan doesn't look very realistic to me as my expectation is that the real user would rather open login page first and then perform the login. i.e. at least 2 requests while you have only 1
4. According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) on next available opportunity

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. I just clicked on encode and it's working fine. Now i can able to login. After logging in, i need to perform some action like vote,like and dislike just like we do in twitter. Please assist me how can i achieve this.